# How can I get KubeVirt to work on AKS or GKE?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, azure-aks

Has anyone been able to get KubeVirt (basically VM in a container) to work with either Azure Kubernetes Serivce (AKS) or Google Kubernetes Enginer (GKE) ? I am getting started with KubeVirt and honestly do not know much about it. Any guidance with help. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In order to use KubeVirt, the underlying node (pool) VMs need to support nested virtualization.  I don't believe that Azure/AKS supports this today.  On the GKE side, we have support for nested virtualization in private preview.

What are you hoping to do with KubeVirt?

Comment: Planning to treat VM's as containers. So instead of VM's (Compute), use GKE to manage both containers and VM's.

Comment: You can +1 / add yourself to the [open issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110507927) in the public tracker and/or  message me on Twitter (@garitweets) or [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/garisingh)  and we can get you set up if interested.